# What does "unpacking portable version" mean?

Tags: installer

English isn't my mother tongue. What does the option "unpacking portable version" mean in this installer window?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means to extract the compressed/packaged files to a folder which could then, conceivably, be moved around to other computers (ie, be "portable").